# my javascript login program isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a basic login program in HTML and javascript, and I think I am entering the correct username and password, but the program keeps returning with the failure alert. I would appreciate help.

*the HTML/JS code**

```js
var username = "jeff"
var password = "whatever"

function login() {
  var possible_username = document.getElementById("username");
  var possible_password = document.getElementById("password");
  if (username == possible_username && password == possible_password) {
    alert("you have successfully logged in!");
  } else {
    alert("you failed to log in !");

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">


</head>


<body>

  <input id="username">
  <input id="password">
  <button onclick="login()">login</button>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to access values, while seeing your code seems that you are accessing elements directly. change ```if (username == possible_username && password == possible_password){``` to ```if (username == possible_username.value && password == possible_password.value){```

Comment: accept/upvote answer if it helped, check [When Someone Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("username")` returns HTML object, to get the `username` you need the value from the object so use `document.getElementById("username").value` instead.

Same goes for password. See below snippet

```js
var username = "jeff";
var password = "whatever";

function login() {
  var possible_username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var possible_password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  if (username == possible_username && password == possible_password) {
    alert("you have successfully logged in!");
  } else {
    alert("you failed to log in !");

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">


</head>


<body>

  <input id="username">
  <input id="password">
  <button onclick="login()">login</button>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the values of the inputs like so:

p.s. you could also make the password input type password

```js
var username = "jeff"
var password = "whatever"

function login() {
  var possible_username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var possible_password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  if (username == possible_username && password == possible_password) {
    alert("you have successfully logged in!");
  } else {
    alert(`you failed to log in with username ${possible_username} and password ${possible_password}  !`);

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">


</head>


<body>

  <input id="username">
  <input id="password" type="password">
  <button onclick="login()">login</button>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```